# Adjust data time zone in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, posixlt

For some reason I can't adjust the time zone by `as.POSIXlt`.

```
time <- "Wed Jun 22 01:53:56 +0000 2016"
t <- strptime(time, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
t
[1] "2016-06-21 21:53:56"
```

Can't change the time zone

```
as.POSIXlt(t, "EST")
[1] "2016-06-21 21:53:56"
as.POSIXlt(t, "Australia/Darwin")
[1] "2016-06-21 21:53:56"
```

Can change the time zone for `Sys.time()`

```
as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "EST")
[1] "2016-09-26 01:47:22 EST"
as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), "Australia/Darwin")
[1] "2016-09-26 16:19:48 ACST"
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I think when running the first two posixlt commands on the vector of time you are actually changing the timezone of the vector but not the time. So it now thinks that 't' is 21:53 in Darwin time instead of EST.

Comment: Try `format(t,  tz='Australia/Darwin', usetz=TRUE) `

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
time <- "Wed Jun 22 01:53:56 +0000 2016"
strptime(time, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
#[1] "2016-06-22 07:23:56"
strptime(time, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz="EST")
#[1] "2016-06-21 20:53:56"
strptime(time, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y', tz="Australia/Darwin")
#[1] "2016-06-22 11:23:56"
```

Answer (score 0):

`strptime` returns a `POSIXlt` object. Calling `as.POSIXlt` on `t` just returns `t`. There is no `as.POSIXlt.POSIXlt` method, so `as.POSIXlt.default` is dispatched. And you can see the first `if` statement checks if `x` inherits the `POSIXlt` class, and returns `x` if that's true.

```
str(t)
# POSIXlt[1:1], format: "2016-06-21 20:53:56"
print(as.POSIXlt.default)
# function (x, tz = "", ...) 
# {
#     if (inherits(x, "POSIXlt")) 
#         return(x)
#     if (is.logical(x) && all(is.na(x))) 
#         return(as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct.default(x), tz = tz))
#     stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s", 
#         deparse(substitute(x)), dQuote("POSIXlt")), domain = NA)
# }
# <bytecode: 0x2d6aa18>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

You either need to use `as.POSIXct` instead of `strptime` and specify the timezone you want, then convert to `POSIXlt`:

```
ct <- as.POSIXct(time, tz = "Australia/Darwin", format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
t <- as.POSIXlt(ct)
```

Or use `strptime` and convert `t` to `POSIXct` and then back to `POSIXlt`:

```
t <- strptime(time, format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
t <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(t, tz = "Australia/Darwin"))
```